# Issue with inheritance in node.js: assignment error when attempting to overwrite prototype for subclass

Tags: javascript, node.js, inheritance

thank you for taking the time to help me out. I'm attempting to learn node.js and have run in to the following problem when working on understanding inheritance:

```
var stream = require('stream');
var util = require('util');

util.inherits(Answers, stream.Readable);

function Answers(opt) {
    stream.Readable.call(this, opt);
    this.quotes = ["yes", "negatory", "possibly"];
    this._index = 0;
}

Answers.prototype._read() = function() {
    if (this._index > this.quotes.length) {
        this.push(null);
    }
    else {
        this.push(this.quotes[this._index]);
        this._index += 1;
    }
};
```

My error states that I have an invalid left-hand side assignment where I attempt to override the prototype of stream.Readable (line 12). I thought the call to

```
util.inherits(Answers, stream.Readable);
```

would allow me to overright the _read() function of stream.Readable. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are no line numbers, which is "line 12"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Answers.prototype._read()` ... you are assigning a value to a function call. Just change it to `Answers.prototype._read = function() ...`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for such a quick answer! ugh, cant believe I missed that, but at least I know I wont make that mistake again and got a good lesson about inheritance in the process.